# Debug webpack-dev-server application inside Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, webpack-dev-server, nestjs

I'm using `webpack-dev-server` to run an Nestjs application inside a Docker container. All is up and running, but I can't debug the application from my VS Code instance. I'm trying to expose the 9229 port using this configuration on the `webpack.config.js`:

```
devServer: {
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 9229,
},
```

When I run `netstat -l` inside the container I can see that node is not listening the 9229 port:

[image: netstat output]

I'm exposing the port 9229 in the Dockerfile and docker-compose files. The Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.16.1-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 9229
CMD [ "yarn", "run", "start:debug"]
```

And the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    open-tuna-api:
        image: opentunaapi
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
            - 9229:9229
        volumes: 
            - ./dist:/usr/src/app/dist
            - ./:/usr/src/app
        networks:
            - open-tuna-network
        expose: 
            - 9229
networks:
    open-tuna-network:
```

And this is the script I'm using to run the application:

```
"start:debug": "webpack --config webpack.config.js && node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
```

My launch configuration is as follow:

```
{
    "name": "Attach",
    "preLaunchTask": "compose-up",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 9229,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}", // the root where everything is based on
    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}", // root of all server files
    "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app", // workspace path which was set in the dockerfile
    "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"], // all compiled JavaScript files
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "restart": true,
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "trace": "verbose",
    "address": "0.0.0.0",
    "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
    ],
}
```

And when I run this configuration with the container up and running I'm receiving a message saying that VS Code cannot connect to the process.

[image: VS Code message]

**So, my question is:** is there a way to debug JavaScript / TypeScript app running on `webpack-dev-server` inside a Docker container? What is wrong in my environment?

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

Apparently my issue has no relation with Docker, since I can reproduce it outside of the container.

Comment: Does `docker-compose ps` show that `open-tuna-api` has `9229:9229` bound in Ports? Try also changing the address in vscode's config to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: More importantly, does it succeed in bringing up the service? Can you access localhost:3000 after beginning to debug?

Comment: Ah, I see the issue, your devserver's port is the same as the node inspector port. You'll want to change the dev server's port to something else (8080? 9000? anything really) and pass that through as well in the docker-compose file's `ports`. It probably fails to start because either node's inspector server or the webpack dev server fails when attempting to bind to :9229 - since they both try to bind to the same port.

Comment: Hi @cubrr, thanks for the help. Yes, I can access the application on localhost:3000. And I tried using `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` in the VS Code config. Also, I changed the `9229` port to `9000` over all the files and the problem persists.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to debug `webpack-dev-server` itself, and after already building the bundle, the dev server is meant to avoid the `webpack --config webpack.config.js` call. what's the server's entry file?

Comment: Hi @MrBar, sorry for the late answer. I'm trying to follow the solution described [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/626#issuecomment-360926051). The entry file is the `dist/server.js` file, specified in the `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: using port 9229 in for both the webserver socket in the webpack config and in inspect for the debug socket should create a conflict and you should only see 9229 listening.. since you still see 3000 despite removing it, this implies you are not configuring the instance you are observing, or need to update the question to reflect the current config?

Comment: Not solving your issue but to see your webpack-dev-server user 'nltp' options: 
netstat -nltp

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your config and make sure you include the `program` field. And point it to the right file under `node_modules`.

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js"
```

That should get you going.

If you want more insight into this, there's a longer conversation that you might find useful - check out [this comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/785#issuecomment-350376019) on the main [webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) GitHub repo.

Comment: Hi @idancali, thanks for your answer. I tried, but I'm getting the same issue. Also, I'm getting a warning from the VS code saying that the "program" property is not allowed. I will take a look at the links you posted.